# cache numba jitted function with arguments include functions objects

Tags: c, python-3.x, performance, numpy, numba

I have some functions like the below sample. The objective is to pass the first function as an argument to the second function and use numba to speed it up. But if I turn the `cache=True` for the second function, there will be error message:

`TypeError: can't pickle weakref objects`

My numba version is `0.49.0`

Is there any solution/alternative solution to this problem so that I can cache the compilation?

```
@njit(cache=True)
def func_test(t1, t2):

    return np.corrcoef(np.argsort(np.argsort(t1)), np.argsort(np.argsort(t2)))

@njit(cache=True)
def test_func_input2(func_1):

    t = list(range(500))
    t2 = list(range(500))
    for i in range(1000):
        t.pop(0)
        t2.pop(0)
        t.append(i)
        t2.append(i)
        a = np.array(t)
        b = np.array(t2)
        x = func_1(a, b)
    return x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import numpy as np
    test_func_input2(func_test)
```

Comment: What is the point of caching the second function,? It seems very basic and compilation time should be very minimal.

Comment: It's just an example. And the my point is that how can I pass in other functions as argument and cache it.

Comment: To be honnest, I don't know if it is implemented. Considering the way numba works, this kind of situation can be hard to deal with. Unless you really need to I wouldn't venture this way.